# Is there an Azure Machine Learning Studio module that works like the Pandas 'mask' method?

Tags: pandas, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to perform the following Python Pandas operation in Azure Machine Learning Studio, but cannot find a module that handles it:

```
df.credit_score = df.credit_score.mask(df.credit_score > 800, df.credit_score / 10)
```

So I'm effectively just trying to find all values in my 'credit_score' column that are greater than 800 and divide them by 10.  I have been unable so far to find a module in AML Studio that does that.

Also, I should add that I'm having issues with my Python script in AML Studio, which is why I'm attempting to replicate all of my code using AML built-in modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no built-in module to do this succinctly (to my knowledge). If you prefer to use built-ins, you could:

1. Use a Split Dataset module to split the entries based on credit
   score
2. Divide the credit score in large-credit-score rows by 10 using
   Apply Math Operation
3. Concatenate the two datasets row-wise with an Add Rows module

Comment: Thanks a lot for that!  I got my Python code working finally, so I didn't need to resort to this after all, but it's good to know that it can be done, just in a bunch of extra steps.  Thanks again.